# Angular 9 Dynamically import modules with dynamic routes

Tags: angular, webpack, module, angular9, dynamic-import

I want to import angular modules dynamically with variable string routes from backend service.
For example my backend service sends to me this response when app is starting(using APP_INITIALIZER).

```
{
    "hostname": "a-tenant",
    "modules": {
        "home": {
            "class": "HomeAModule",
            "path": "home-a.module",
         },
    },
},
```

My app structure is:

[image: project structure]

So i want to import a module like this

```
const path = `./tenants/${response.hostname}/home/${response.modules.home.path}`;

import(path).then(m => m[response.modules.home.class]);
```

My final import code should be like this in runtime:

```
import('./tenants/a-tenant/home/home-a.module').then(m => m.HomeAModule);
```

But i'm getting this error, i think webpack does not handle dynamic loads like this.

Thank you for your help :)

[image: Error]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I"m in a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304831/how-do-you-load-a-dynamic-module-by-variable-in-angular-9

Comment: No unfortunately it is not possible. I am importing modules with static paths right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using dynamic string for dynamic imports is impossible

Comment: [Here](https://blog.mgechev.com/2019/05/11/dynamic-imports-javascript/) is a good explanation of why...
Dynamic imports are fantastic for code-splitting on a granular level. They allow us to provide lazy-loading boundaries in our application. In the same time, because of their dynamical nature, they often will enable us to sneak in code that requires runtime data for resolution of the imported module ... we should be extremely cautious because we limit the capabilities of the tools that we’re using. We sacrifice automatic bundling of lazy-loaded chunks, type inference, and much more.